# Nesting doskey macros

Tags: cmd, doskey

I'd just like to know if there is a way to call one doskey macro from another. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
>doskey cleanpix=%PATH%\cleanpix.bat
>doskey cp=cleanpix
```

What am I doing wrong?

If there's no way to do what I'm trying to do, is there another way to define `cp` to the same commands as the defintion of `cleanpix` without typing all that shit out all over again? Besides CTRL+C, CTRL+V of course.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe DOSKEY macros can call one another directly.  You're probably better off using a quicky batch file like this.  Create a file called (say) `cp.cmd` and put it somewhere in your path.  Its contents should be:

```
call %PATHTOCLEANPIX%\cleanpix.bat %*
```

One other note about your question - I assume that `%PATH%` was an example for the question, and not the literal value you're trying to use.  `PATH` is a built-in environment variable that holds a list of directories where `cmd` should look for executables.