# DOSKEY recall alias

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, alias, doskey

Is it possible to recall an alias with DOSKEY?
Simple example .. I wish to do something like that:

```
DOSKEY a=someCommand
DOSKEY b=someOtherCommand
DOSKEY c=andAThirdCommand

:: How to do this? -> DOSKEY all=a+b+c
```

I already know that I can do this by writing this:

```
DOSKEY all=someCommand ^& someOtherCommand ^& andAThirdCommand
```

but in the sense of reusing stuff I'd like to reuse my defined aliases from above.
Is it possible like I desire?

Thanks!

PS: Saw this here, but it's not a satisfying answer. It seems that it won't work though. :(

Comment: Nobody knows an answer? Too bad :( Well I can live with it I guess.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208993/nesting-doskey-macros

Answer (score 3):

Good question, hard to answer... However, I can suggest a workaround with a simple batch script(s).

Suppose we have defined `doskey a=commandA` and `doskey a=commandB` and `doskey c=commandC` macros.

1. **Static** approach: let's  name our script e.g. `dem` (**de**fine **m**acro) and place it somewhere in your `path`. Then `dem acb a c b` should **define a new macro** `acb` (ready to further use) as follows: `doskey acb=commandA $T commandC $T commandB`. That script could be established by a little adaptation from the script `dsk` provided (hint: instead of *launching* a macro text, *constitute* the text for new macro, but be aware of another escaping).
2. **Dynamic** approach: let's  name our script e.g. `dsk` (**d**o**sk**ey) and place it somewhere in your `path`. Then `dsk a b c` should **call macros** `a`, `b` and `c` in that sequence. Number of parameters (macro names) passed to script is not limited. The script works well with very simply defined macros, but

   - allows `%` percent sign use like in `doskey a=echo %variable%` macro and/or even `for` loops like in `doskey a=for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b /s *.txt') do @echo %G`;
   - allows `$T` concatenated commands in a macro (equivalent to `&` in a batch file) like `doskey a=dir $T set`; done by replacing `$T` with `&` (in rare cases does not suffice, then need to split and perform commands separately).

Known issues and/or restrictions (impossible to resolve without knowing more about real structure of macros used); the `dsk` script

- a `for` loop could bring problems with `%%parameter` variable; vetoed to use in a macro: `%%{` (outer loop) and `%%?` `%%@` (inner loop)
- does not make allowance for piping or redirecting like `doskey a=dir ^> somefile`;
- does not make allowance for `^&` concatenated commands in a macro (but allows `doskey` intrinsic `$T` concatenation);
- does not make allowance for launching batch `.bat` or `.cmd` scripts (needs `call %xitem%` instead of `%xitem%` in the `:doItem` procedure (cca 50th line);
- if a macro name isn't found, it's simply overskipped...

The script `dsk` is as follows:

```
:: dsk.bat
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "CheckOnly=0"

set "DoneList="
set "ToDoList="
set "xitem=x"
for %%{ in (%*) do (
  set "_G_found=0"
  echo.
  for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%? in ('doskey /macros') do (
    if /i "%%{"=="%%?" (
      for /F "tokens=*" %%_ in ("%%@") do set "item=%%_"
      if /i "!item:~0,3!"=="for" set "item=!item:%%=%%%%!"
      if "%CheckOnly%"=="1" (
          echo :  to do: '!item!'
      ) else (
          echo :  To Do: '!item!'
          call :doItem !item!
      )
      set "DoneList=!DoneList! +%%{"
      set "_G_found=1"
    ) 
  )
  if "!_G_found!"=="0" (
    set "DoneList=!DoneList! -%%{"
    echo :  macro: [%%{] ^(not found^)
    if "!ToDoList!"=="" set "ToDoList=!ToDoList!, [%%{]"
    if "!ToDoList!"=="!ToDoList:[%%{]=!" set "ToDoList=!ToDoList!, [%%{]"
  )
)
echo.
echo :  
echo :    trailing progress report
echo :  
if "%ToDoList%"=="" (
    echo :    all found: %DoneList:~1%
) else (
    echo :    +found, -not found: %DoneList:~1%
    echo :   %ToDoList:~2% not found in macro name list 
)
echo :    end of batch %~f0
echo :  
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof

:doItem
  set "xitem=%*"
  set "xitem=%xitem:$T=&%"
  %xitem%
@goto :eof
```

With next scenario:

```
d:\bat>doskey /macros
y=for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /b rand.bat') do @echo %g
x=dir /B /AD $T dir /B /AD "D:\Remote\bat\COCL\bu bu bu" $T set y
a=echo CheckOnly=%CheckOnly%
b=rand.bat
```

and `dsk y b a x n` call gives next output:

```
d:\bat>dsk y b a x n

:  To Do: 'for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b rand.bat') do @echo %%g'
rand.bat

:  To Do: 'rand.bat'
The system cannot find the batch label specified - doItem

:  To Do: 'echo CheckOnly=%CheckOnly%'
CheckOnly=0

:  To Do: 'dir /B /AD $T dir /B /AD "D:\Remote\bat\COCL\bu bu bu" $T set y'
files
a.dot 1.dot 2.dot 3
Environment variable y not defined

:  macro: [n] (not found)

:
:    trailing progress report
:
:    +found, -not found: +y +b +a +x -n
:   [n] not found in macro name list
:    end of batch d:\bat\dsk.bat
:
d:\bat>
```

The script is rather verbose for debugging purposes (and variable `CheckOnly` as well, with values `1`= only *echo* commands, `0`= echo and *execute* commands in a macro).

Comment: doskey is a simple wrapper around the console API, so it may be more straightforward to write a little program that calls [`GetConsoleAlias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`AddConsoleAlias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).